# Visual Studio 2010: Adding commands to toolbar

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I've been playing with the RC of Visual Studio 2010, trying to set it up similarly to my VS 2008 installation. In VS 2008, I have added a couple of commands to the standard toolbar; *Edit > Outlining > Toggle All*, and *Edit > Outlining > Collapse to Definitions*. These commands don't have native images, so I created a couple and added them to the toolbar buttons using the VS 2008 Customize dialog, like this: I right-click the toolbar to bring up its context menu, then I select *Customize* to open the Customize dialog. At that point, I can right click the button to which I want to add an icon. I get another context menu that lets me paste a button image or set the button image to a standard image.

I tried doing the same thing in VS 2010 RC, and it works the same, up to the point where the Customize dialog opens. But at that point, I can't right click my added button to set its image. So, that brings me to my question: Is there a way that I can assign an image to a command that I add to a VS 2010 toolbar, assuming the command doesn't have a native image? Thanks.

Comment: +1 just for pointing out where to find the *Outlining*-commands down the menu-tree (an information MSDN didn't unravel to me in about 5 Minutes of searching). Thanks to your question, I was able successfully add those commands to my toolbar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few of the configuration options changes (and some were lost) in VS2010 (as part of the rework in WPF).

You can do some customisation in the Commands tab of the customised dialogue (that you get to by right clicking on the toolbar). But controlling the image is not one of them.

See this VS team blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/visualstudio/archive/2009/12/14/customizing-visual-studio-2010.aspx

Answer (score 7):

**Command Image Changing Extension**

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150928075859/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/06/17/command-image-changing-extension.aspx)